# Leaving out the max value in an Enumeration

Tags: c#, optimization, enum

This is part of a school assignment and I came up with the following solution to leave out the max value in a Enumeration:

```
static void Opdracht3()
{
    List<int> values = new List<int>();
    foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)))
    {
        values.Add(value);
    }

    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        if (value != values.Max())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Naam: {0}, Waarde: {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Opleidingen), value), value);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I improve this piece of (working) code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, most of the leg work is done for us in the framework.  Enum.GetValues returns the list sorted ascending already, via the underlying implementation of [Type.GetEnumData](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/d5cd3cb0c6c2b6c1.html).

With that in mind, you can use LINQ for the rest, retrieving all but the last value:

```
static void Opdracht3()
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)).Cast<Opleidingen>().ToList();
    var valuesExceptMax = values.Take(values.Count - 1);

    foreach (var value in valuesExceptMax)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Naam: {0}, Waarde: {1}", value, (int) value);
    }
}
```

Since we retrieve the enum values themselves rather than casting to int up front, we can eliminate the Enum.GetName calls.  Passing an enum value into a string format will use the name for us (see: [Enum.ToString()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/1365cfeffd45409d.html)).

In case you are hesitant to assume sorting up-front, it's pretty trivial to toss a call to `.OrderBy(x => x)` just before the `.ToList()` in our first LINQ statement.  However, if you're going to order the list, it would be simpler to sort descending and skip the first (max) value, so we can drop the `.ToList()`:

```
static void Opdracht3()
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)).Cast<Opleidingen>().OrderByDescending(x => x);
    var valuesExceptMax = values.Skip(1);

    foreach (var value in valuesExceptMax)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Naam: {0}, Waarde: {1}", value, (int) value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer, as it's simpler to not need to cache the max value and then check each element in the group.

Answer (score 10):

This is not efficient:

> ```
> foreach (int value in values)
> {
>     if (value != values.Max())
> ```

Because in every iteration, you recalculate `values.Max()`, when it would be enough to do it once, before starting the loop.

Also, you don't need to create `values` as a `List<int>`. As a result, the method can be simplified:

```
static void Opdracht3()
{
    int maxValue = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)).Cast<int>().Max();

    foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)))
    {
        if (value != maxValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Naam: {0}, Waarde: {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Opleidingen), value), value);
        }
    }
}
```

And as [@blueraja](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2050/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft) pointed out, to reduce duplication even further, it's good to cache `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)).Cast<int>()` in a variable:

```
static void Opdracht3()
{
    int[] values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)).Cast<int>();
    int maxValue = values.Max();

    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        if (value != maxValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Naam: {0}, Waarde: {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Opleidingen), value), value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use .Max() on the Enum.GetValues() though. But indeed, calculating .Max() before the iteration would be better. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it does. What was the reason it needed a cast? When I hover over GetValues it already says it creates an array. What type of array does it make? Btw I already tried it with a cast before, but I put (int) & (int[]) infront of it, instead of using .Cast<int>()

Comment: I would go even further and store `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)).Cast<int>()` in a variable, since it's used twice *(the second cast is implicit)*

Comment: @anthonytimmers The `.Cast<int>()` method is a LINQ extension that casts each element in the collection to an integer. Without that, you're dealing with a collection of enum values. There is no "max" of an enum, only the corresponding integer of each value. Your attempts at `(int)`, and `(int[])` in the front cast the RESULT of the operation to the given data type, not the individual elements before attempting to find the `Max()`.

Comment: @anthonytimmers check out Dan's answer, it's better than mine, you should accept that instead! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62350/12390

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Opleidingen)) as int[];    
var maxValue = values.Max();    
var notMax = values.Where(v => v != maxValue);

foreach (var value in notMax)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Naam: {0}, Waarde: {1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Opleidingen), value), value);
}
```

But I did'nt test that. Could also use linq ForEach (on list) to make it in one line probably.

Calling Max() in every iteration is not a good idea. Unlike in the accepted answer, getting values from enum should be made once.

Comment: notMax is an IEnumerable<bool>